# Cannot plot circle with ezplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot 6 circles in figure MATLAB. But it's cannot appear.

I have think of this code is correct, and I try to give axis limits. But it cannot fixing my problem.

```
clear all;
clc;
p=[8 9 3 4 7 4];
rtopi=[3 4 16 25 34 25];
n=length(p);
for ii=1:n
    f=@(x,y)(x-p(ii)).^2+(y).^2-rtopi(ii)^2;
    gambar=ezplot(f);
    set(gambar,'color','k','linewidth',2);
    grid on;
    axis equal;
    set(gca,'Color','y');
    xlabel('Real');
    ylabel('Imaginary');
    title('Discs');
    axis([-30 30 -30 30]);
end
```

This is the result :

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the .* in the function definition, just use x^2 not x.^2.

Use 'hold on' before end of loop

Move the background color, grid on, title etc. outside the loop.

And most importantly, declare xmin, xmax for the ezplot. Default is (-2pi to 2pi).
Try: gambar = ezplot(f,[xmin,xmax}) and use the plot limits for the xmin and xmax